# Frame buffer module of python

Tags: python, framebuffer

I'm looking for a python module which can display `jpg` or `png` file to `/dev/fb0` directly.

I hope the the module can call and display the picture on screen by like this:

```
show_photo(path_to_jpg, x, y, dev='/dev/fb0')
```

I had searched such kind of python module on google for several days, and I found the link: [[Module] Python Frame Buffer](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2001-August/000979.html), but the website was not found.

Now, I'm using C program and call by `os.system()` function, and it is too slow. Does there has a python module which can show the picture directly to frame buffer, and support static picture, marquee? It will be better if the module also support playing video file like `mplayer`.

Comment: `fbi` player followed by `pkill fbi` does what you want. Both would be external processes to launch. You say you write C and ask for python - not sure I understand, but I don't think python has anything for this out of the box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you may use pygame.

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about

> Pygame uses either opengl, directx, windib, X11, **linux frame buffer**,
>   and many other different backends...

**UPDATE:**
Simple example:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

pygame.init()

size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.gif")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

screen.fill(black)
screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
pygame.display.flip()

time.sleep(5)
```

Run:

```
SDL_NOMOUSE=1 python ./ball.py
```

Comment: Yes, I did find `pygame`, but I just need the simple function to show picture to frame buffer. And there has a lot of tutorial about `pygame` to draw pixel, but I only need to show picture static or like marquee. Do you have some idea about this?

Comment: Thanks for your example. I got an error on `open /dev/snd/seq failed`, and I think you can add `sudo modprobe snd-seq-midi` at first to avoid it. and the script need to run as root, or it will get an error `pygame.error: video system not initialized`.

Comment: Probably, your user should be added to 'video' and 'audio' groups.

Comment: Actually, I need the program to run once, exit and leave the image on screen. pygame will clear the screen after exit; if you want to show the image, pygame need to run background. So it's not fit my need. Anyway, thanks for your example !!