# How to show a fullscreen image from the command line interface without a window manager using Python

Tags: python, image, command-line, debian

I have a python script that, when executed, wait's until it gets input from the user. I now want to know if it is posible to keep showing an image fullscreen until the user has given the input? I have searched for a solution but all i can find are tools that window managers to show the picture, but this is not installed. It'll probably only run on Debian.

I'm kind of searching for the same idea as omxplayer, but instead of movies it has to display pictures.

Comment: Try using Xlib to draw directly on root window, or even XServer is also not installed?

Comment: Pygame is probably your best bet. See: [Frame buffer module of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608454/frame-buffer-module-of-python).

Comment: @AnuragUniyal nope, XServer is not installed. Tried a view packages (imagemagick and one i don't remember) and they both said they needed XServer running.

Comment: @PedroRomano: maybe you want to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) is probably the easiest way of displaying an image fullscreen on the *Linux* framebuffer or on the *X Windows* root window (i.e. without a window manager).

The answers to the question [Frame buffer module of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608454/frame-buffer-module-of-python) have all the details on how to achieve this.