# Graphics on Linux without full-blown window manager?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, graphics, touchscreen

Is it possible to do graphics on Linux without installing and using a full blown window manager like Gnome/KDE etc?

I am working on an embedded system with a touch screen and I just need to generate Python plots and perhaps have a few buttons to select which plots are displayed. There is no mouse or keyboard.

I do not want to use a windowing system because that would be total overkill for this project. Is there any way I can just display my plots and buttons in fixed locations on the screen and be done with it? Platform is Debian Linux.

Comment: You can use X.org without a window manager.

Comment: With [Kivy](http://kivy.org/) you can create Python script for devices with touch screen.

Comment: Study [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.5.html) specs.. Or use e.g. Gtk above [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are libs available. Years ago I used svgalib. Games like Quake used it as well.

http://www.svgalib.org

I may be behind the times, however, so I am not sure how current this alternative is. It seems a bit out of date.

Answer (score 2):

You can program w/ [Xlib](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/) directly.  There looks to be a [python port](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/); I've included a link to a manual for the native C library since the python docs look skimpy and that may help with some of the concepts.

In your question you've perhaps conflated the concept of *window manager* with *windowing system*.  GNOME and KDE are actually *desktop environments* built on top of a *window manager*.  The latter are generally much lighter weight than the former and can often be used standalone (openbox, fvwm, et. al.).

These are in turn built on top of the *windowing system*, which is Xorg.  It is possible to do graphical stuff without that using the [kernel framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer), which [apparently is an option for pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608565/1151724).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to not even have X at all.  You could try using SDL w/ framebuffer support - a thread regarding this approach can be found here: [Using OpenGL Without X-Window System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036650/using-opengl-without-x-window-system)